# How can I upload large files from browser to S3 using Laravel in a load balanced environment?

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-s3, laravel-6, amazon-elb

I have an application that allows users to upload relatively large video files, which are stored on S3. We previously used [flow-php-server](https://github.com/flowjs/flow-php-server) to chunk uploads over multiple requests that are then assembled and stored on S3. Unfortunately, this method no longer works, as we recently upgraded our server architecture to a load balanced environment and chunks are being split across the multiple servers behind our load balancer.

What is the solution to this problem? I am under the impression that if we split file uploads over multiple requests, we can make no guarantees about which server it hits so uploads will fail. Does this mean I'll have to settle with single request uploads and deal with browser single request file size limits? Is there another way around this?

I'm not sure if the solution requires configuring the server/load balancer to somehow direct uploads for the same file to the same server, or if there's a different method I can implement on the front/back ends to accommodate this.

Comment: Sounds like the easiest solution would be to implement `Sticky Sessions` on the load balancer, which will ensure that requests coming from a specific source are always routed to the same server. You could google `sticky sessions {your load balancer}`.

Comment: While sticky session is the exact answer to your question, you could take a different approach and upload directly to S3 via a signed link. After the upload just call an endpoint with the corresponding path and you can process your files. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html